# import statement is not working in typescript

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, es6-modules

I imported another class in my typescript file. same import statement generated in js file also. But when i run this application in browser, that import statement throwing error like "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import". So please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: [`import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import): _"This feature is only beginning to be implemented in browsers natively at this time. It is implemented in many transpilers, such as the Traceur Compiler, Babel, Rollup, and Webpack."_

Answer (score 0):

You must use [browserify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/browserify) or [webpack](https://github.com/webpack/webpack) to handle module loading/bundling.